Value type mismatch, how should I fix the implementation?
enum A {
    AA = 'AA',
    BB = 'BB'
}

export interface OptionsA {a: number}
export interface OptionsB {b: string}

export interface ValuesA {a: boolean}
export interface ValuesB {b: boolean | null}

export interface FirstMapA {
    [A.AA]: OptionsA,
    [A.BB]: OptionsB
}

export interface SecondMapA {
    [A.AA]: ValuesA,
    [A.BB]: ValuesB
}

export class SomeThing<Type extends keyof FirstMapA> {
    type: Type;
    value: SecondMapA[Type];

    doThings(): void {
        if (this.type === A.AA) {
            this.value.
        }
    }
}

In this example, in doThings functions this.value is ValuesA | ValuesB, but it only should be ValuesA, what am i doing wrong?

TypeScript is not able to infer that this.type === A.AA narrows the type of this.value to ValuesA. Instead, TypeScript continues to consider this.value as either ValuesA or ValuesB.
You can use a type assertion to help TypeScript understand that this.value should be ValuesA when this.type is A.AA.
enum A {
  AA = "AA",
  BB = "BB",
}

export interface OptionsA {
  a: number;
}
export interface OptionsB {
  b: string;
}

export interface ValuesA {
  a: boolean;
}
export interface ValuesB {
  b: boolean | null;
}

export interface FirstMapA {
  [A.AA]: OptionsA;
  [A.BB]: OptionsB;
}

export interface SecondMapA {
  [A.AA]: ValuesA;
  [A.BB]: ValuesB;
}

export class SomeThing<Type extends keyof FirstMapA> {
  type: Type;
  value: SecondMapA[Type];

  doThings(): void {
    if (this.type === A.AA) {
      const valueA = this.value as ValuesA; // Type assertion
      valueA.a; // Now TypeScript understands this is ValuesA
    }
  }
}



Thanks, i was afraid its the only solution...

It’s not actually. Alternatively, You can use a type guard function to narrow the type. Though, for things like you mentioned I would go with type assertion.
